# Set Startup Display Form using VBA

Tags: vba, startup

Is it possible to change the Startup Display Form using VBA?  It is very easy to do using the Access Options page, but I am trying to do this from within VBA and nothing seems to work.  I've searched all over looking for Database properties or settings that would allow for this.

Does anyone have any insight into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about directly changing the startup form property but what you could try is creating a form that can load your desired startup form. This way you can for instance store the form to be loaded in a config table and change it via VBA.

Downside is that effectively two forms are started and not one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the autoexec macro. It'll run code for you when your database is launched. Use this to load a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a form to automatically open up in access VBA by [setting the built-in database property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/properties-collection-dao) `StartUpForm` to the name of the form.

To remove this form from startup you can simply delete that property.

```
Private Sub debug_properties()

    ListProperties

    SetProperty "StartupForm", 10, "Form_Name"    'UPDATE TO YOUR FORM NAME
'    DeleteProperty "StartupForm"
    
'    ListProperties
    
End Sub

Public Function SetProperty(ByVal propName As String, ByVal propType As Long, propValue As Variant)

''SetProperty will create a property if it doesn't exist
    
    On Error GoTo SetProperty_Err
    
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database         ''Reference: Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library    'ACEDAO.DLL    'Access.References.AddFromGuid "{4AC9E1DA-5BAD-4AC7-86E3-24F4CDCECA28}", 0, 0
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    
    Dim prps As DAO.Properties      ''Reference: Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library    'ACEDAO.DLL    'Access.References.AddFromGuid "{4AC9E1DA-5BAD-4AC7-86E3-24F4CDCECA28}", 0, 0
    Set prps = dbs.Properties
    
    ''attempt to set property
    prps(propName) = propValue
    
    
SetProperty_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
    
SetProperty_Err:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3270   ''The property was not found
            ''create property
            Dim prp As DAO.Property
            Set prp = dbs.CreateProperty(Name:=propName, _
                                         Type:=propType, _
                                         Value:=propValue)
            ''add new property to collection
            dbs.Properties.Append prp
        Case Else
            MsgBox "SetProperty, Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    End Select
    
    Resume SetProperty_Exit
    
End Function

Private Function DeleteProperty(ByVal propName As String)

    On Error GoTo DeleteProperty_Err
    
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database         ''Reference: Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library    'ACEDAO.DLL    'Access.References.AddFromGuid "{4AC9E1DA-5BAD-4AC7-86E3-24F4CDCECA28}", 0, 0
    Set dbs = CurrentDb             
    
    dbs.Properties.Delete propName
    
    
DeleteProperty_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function
    
DeleteProperty_Err:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 3265   ''The property was not found
            MsgBox "Property '" & propName & "' does not exist."
        Case Else
            MsgBox "DeleteProperty, Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
    End Select
    
    Resume DeleteProperty_Exit
    
End Function

Private Sub ListProperties()

''Lists DB properties created in code (as well as built-in properties)

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database             ''Reference: Microsoft Office 16.0 Access database engine Object Library    'ACEDAO.DLL    'Access.References.AddFromGuid "{4AC9E1DA-5BAD-4AC7-86E3-24F4CDCECA28}", 0, 0
    Set dbs = Application.CurrentDb
    
    Debug.Print vbCrLf & Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss") & " ======="
    
    Debug.Print """" & Mid(CurrentDb.Name, _
                            InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, "\") + 1, _
                            InStr(CurrentDb.Name, ".accdb") - InStrRev(CurrentDb.Name, "\") - 1) & _
                """ Properties: "
    
    On Error Resume Next    'skips the 'connection' property which has no 'value' for some reason
    
    Dim prp As DAO.Property
    For Each prp In dbs.Properties
        Debug.Print prp.Name & ": " & prp.Value
    Next prp
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub
```